# Sinus curve with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this code snippet and have following questions:

1. What does the p stand for in function(p)?
2. {path: new SineWave}
   What does this expression mean, what does path stand for?
3. What is
   the stop() goof for in the example code?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WPnQG/471/) in firefox only

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.SineWave = SineWave = function() {
  this.css = function(p) {
    s = Math.sin((p-1)*50);
    x = (100 - p*100) * 10;
    y = s * 20;
    return {top: y + "px", left: x + "px"};
  } 
}

window.loop = loop = function(){       
        $("#nyan").stop().animate(
        {path: new SineWave}, 
        50000, 
        "linear"

    );
}

loop();
});
```

Comment: Is fiddle supposed to draw something?

Comment: The example animates a box along a sinus curve

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome, guess because it refuses to run script from raw.github (error from console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the p stand for in function(p)?

It's just an argument name.

Then, if you call the function like `this.css(123)`, `p` will become `123`.

---

> What does `{path: new SineWave}` mean, what does path
>   stand for?

I creates an object which has a property `"path"`.

For example

```
var obj = {
   a: 123
}
obj.a; // 123
abj['a']; // 123
```

In your case, the value is another object (instead of number `123`) which is an instance of `SineWave` constructor. That means it inherits properties and methods from `SineWave.prototype`.

---

> What is the `stop()` goof for in the example code?

`.stop()` is a [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) which *stops the currently-running animation on the matched elements*.

Comment: Thank you! I printed p to the console and its value is p=1, then it shrinks to zero. Why ist it 1 and why does it shrink?

Comment: Good question! If you go to [jQuery's source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js), `jQuery.fn` is extended with `animate` (the method you call), which passes your object to `Animation`, which passes it to `deferred.promise`. And now I'm lost, I don't know enough of jQuery, maybe you should ask it in another question.